# Get difference between dates and format with 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, angular8

How do I transform the milliseconds from `date.now()` into the format `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` or transform a string with a date into milliseconds.

I also have a string which returns the following:

`appointment: "21/11/2019 18:00:30"`

I need to get the **difference** in hours between the **date.now** and **appointment** date

Comment: Please update from Angular 5 to a more recent version. Angular 5 isn't supported anymore

Comment: @ShamPooSham thats not possible and also doesnt depend on me hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To transform a date, you can use **DatePipe**:

```
let datePipe = new DatePipe();
datePipe.transform(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss');
```

To get the difference between Date.now() and a date, you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59486883/8718377), or you can use **moment** like that:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

// ...

const difference = moment(moment(),"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(appointment,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))
```

You will need to install `moment` like that:

```
npm install --save moment
```

Comment: injected moment.js just to get the datedif is not considered a will solution , but I case you are use it is a great library 

Comment: @veben what would date be? Date.now?

Comment: @PLATANIUM, it would be the date you want to transform

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert date string to a valid format like this `"2019-11-21T18:00:30";` and then get the difference using `.getTime()`

Try like this:

```
let difference = Math.abs(new Date().getTime() - new Date(this.appointment).getTime());

var seconds = difference / 1000;
var minutes = difference / 1000 / 60;
var hours = minutes / 60;

console.log("Difference in Hours",hours)
console.log("Difference in minutes",minutes)
console.log("Difference in seconds",seconds)
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ikbz28?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment:  well done , but can you give more explanation about the date format this will be helpful

Comment: thanks @Adrita for updating the answer it's more helpful now

Answer (score 2):

Here is [working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c6jcmd)

```
var d = new Date,
dformat = [d.getDate(),
          d.getMonth()+1 ,
           d.getFullYear()].join('/')+' '+
          [d.getHours(),
           d.getMinutes(),
           d.getSeconds()].join(':');
           console.log(dformat)
```

**OUT PUT**

26/12/2019 15:48:17

Answer (score 1):

Hours difference:

```
const dateAppointment = new Date('1/11/2019 18:00:30');
const currentDate = new Date();
console.log(`currentDate is `, currentDate );
const diffTime = Math.abs(currentDate - dateAppointment);
const diffHours = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)); 
console.log(`diffHours is`, diffHours );
```

An example:

```js
const dateAppointment = new Date('1/11/2019 18:00:30');
const currentDate = new Date();
console.log(`currentDate is `, currentDate );
const diffTime = Math.abs(currentDate - dateAppointment);
const diffHours = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)); 
console.log(`diffHours is`, diffHours );
```

**UPDATE:**

HTML:

```
<p>currentDate is {{ currentDate | date : 'dd.MM.y, HH:mm:ss' }} </p>
<p>dateAppointment is {{ dateAppointment | date : 'dd.MM.y, HH:mm:ss' }} </p>
<p>differenceHour is {{ differenceHour }} </p>
```

TypeScript:

```
 name = 'Angular';
 currentDate = new Date();
 dateAppointment = new Date('1/11/2019 18:00:30');
 differenceHour = 0;

 constructor(){    
     const diffTime = Math.abs(this.currentDate - this.dateAppointment);
     this.differenceHour = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)); 
 }
```

[An stackblitz example can be seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dh49tw)

Comment: im getting this error: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362) with the following line of code: const diffTime = Math.abs(currentDate - dateAppointment);

Answer (score 1):

There's is one way to do it without 3rd party

```
let date = new Date(Date.now());
date = `${date.getDate()}:${date.getMonth() + 1}:${date.getFullYear()}:${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;
```

and there's a way using angular if you use Angular, you can use "DatePipe", with transform method, like that:

```
datePipe.transform(date, 'dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss');
```

and to get the difference btw dates there is only one way

```
const currentDate = new Date('26/12/2019');
const appoinemnt = new Date('15/1/2020');
const diffTime = Math.abs(appoinemnt - currentDate );
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
console.log(diffDays);
```

Comment: good job  but you need to mention you have inject the Date pipe